# How to setup my virtualhost for laravel project if my domain is like example.com/laraproject?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5.1, virtualhost

I need host a laravel app in http://example.com/laraproject , i cant use the simple domain example.com , i try to setup my virtualhost on apache, .env file but : 
Examples:
VirtualHost apache

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ServerPath /larapoject
DocumentRoot /var/www/laraproject/public

DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory "/var/www/laraproject/public">
   Options -Indexes
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.env file :

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_DOMAIN=example.com/laraproject/
APP_HOME=http://example.com/laraproject/
APP_STATIC=http://example.com/laraproject/
```

The default route works fine, but, the problem is when i try to redirect to others routes, for example.

For
example.com/laraproject load the home page .
For 
example.com/laraproject/section1 not load the page, because not resolve the route for some reason.

Laravel version 5.1
Apache 2.4
PHP 5.5.3

Any idea ? I tried everything to resolve this problem but i cant .

Thanks at all  .

Comment: http://mackhankins.com/blog/laravel-5-virtual-host-for-an-apache-subdirectory

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite module? Not sure if you use linux or windows or mac. So you have to google how to enable it.

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled, my OS ubuntu Server 14

Comment: My routes.php , part: 
`Route::post("/login/access", "LoginController@login");
Route::get("/", "LoginController@index");`
"loging/acces" dont work but "/" yes.